# How to shorthand a callback wtih a single line?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following callback:

```
$('#btnDoStuff').on('click', function processBasicInfo() {    
  $('#modalBasicInfo').modal('show');
});
```

Since the function contains only a single line, is there a way to shorten it, like this?

```
$('#btnDoStuff').on('click', $('#modalBasicInfo').modal('show'));
```

or a variation thereof?

P.S. Needs to support browsers all the way down to IE11.

Comment: Weird that you would want to do that.

Comment: @Phil not so fast.... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to make it even shorten, but i guess you could drop the function name.

```
$('#btnDoStuff').on('click', function() { return $('#modalBasicInfo').modal('show') });
```

Or you could bind the function with all of its arguments:

```
$('#btnDoStuff').on('click', $('#modalBasicInfo').modal.bind($('#modalBasicInfo'), 'show'));
```

Or if you intend to use babel you could use an arrow function.

```
$('#btnDoStuff').on('click', () => $('#modalBasicInfo').modal('show'));
```

Comment: Need to support IE11

Comment: use babel then, the question is kinda non-sensical anyways

Comment: @ospfranco I'm sure if op was using Babel, the need to specify up to which browser to support is irrelevant.

Comment: ah, sorry, I missed the IE11 part.

Comment: If you are going to copy the bind like the others, you should at least remove the fat arrow.... lol

Comment: @epascarello to be fair i was in a fiddle trying to figure out other ways of doing it, so i didn't know there were other answers until after i added mine. But yes. I was i bit to quick when i copied my arrow function example.

Comment: Yes, lambda like syntax is what I was looking for.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like IE supports it.

Answer (score 1):

You can `bind` the `modal` call for the eventhandler

```
$('#btnDoStuff').on('click', $('#modalBasicInfo').modal.bind($('#modalBasicInfo'),'show'));
```

Answer (score 1):

No clue why you would want to do it, but you can use .bind(), but makes no sense.

```js
$("button").on("click", $(".modal").modal.bind($(".modal"), "show"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button>Foo</button>
<div class="modal">Bar</div>
```